# Mental Approach to solving prime checking?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop a program that would print to Console all primes between 1 and 100. I ran into trouble trying to conceptualize the problem. There are multiple nested loops and I lost track of the logic. Here's the incomplete, code/pseudocode mess:

```
using System;

class Prime_Screening
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This program screens all numbers between 1 and 100 for primes and displays the results.");

            for (int numberToPrimeCheck = 2; numberToPrimeCheck <= 100; numberToPrimeCheck++)
            {
                for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= Math.Sqrt(numberToPrimeCheck); divisor++)
                {
                    int remainder = 0;
                    while (remainder = 0)
                    {
                        remainder = numberToPrimeCheck % divisor;
                        if (remainder != 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

It's a huge mess. I don't know where to start on this program. Logically, it looks like a big ball of string. I know that remainder = numberToPrimeCheck % divisor is the heart of this problem, but do I start there or at the first loop?

When writing a small program like this, how and where do you start thinking about it? I'm a beginner programmer, but books don't teach you where and how to think about a programming problem. Can someone teach me the thought process to solve a problem like this?

EDIT: I get it, the question is too broad. But some questions aren't narrow by nature but necessary to becoming a good programmer. SO is being too restrictive. I don't just want the answer to my code, I want to learn how to think about and solving programming problems in general.

Comment: Yes, I was about to make the same comment.  This question is of poor quality, and should be flagged as such, but Code_Steel is new.  Let's leave constructive comments, first, and hopefully he can clean up his question to become a bit more appropriate for the site.

Comment: The answer is "very carefully"

Comment: It doesn't matter, people just want to click and have reputation instead of really helping :((

Comment: @usar, down-voting doesn't help ones personal reputation.

Comment: @RLH Oh, yes, you're right, what an embarrassing comment I made, ofc, it removes 1 ridiculous holy point of reputation.

Comment: @usar voting down questions has no effect on reputation. Only voting down answers cost rep.

Comment: Actually, downvoting a question doesn't cost any rep points. Downvoting an answer does though (-1). I think you are copping downvotes because you are combining two questions (why isn't my code working) and (how to become a good programmer). If you edit your question to be purely about the code, then you wouldn't attract downvotes. Asking broad questions that are difficult to answer is actively discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: I will also recommend the CodeReview SE site for more generalist approaches to improving your software engineering  skills: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also you can try this series of videos by V Anton Spraul: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgzpqlF54lo

Comment: It may help to try to break the problem down into steps that you write as comments. Fiddle about with those until it makes some sort of sense, then write the code to fill in the gaps. As a beginner you face the challenge of not having a broad grasp of the tools available. That will come with time, grasshopper.

Comment: re: Your comment that "SO is being too restrictive." Your question isn't invalid, this simply isn't the proper forum for it. Neither is a dentists convention. Perhaps you can find a more suitable forum in the StackExchange family or farther afield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;

class Prime_Screening
    {
    bool prime;
    static void Main()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Prime numbers x, where: 0 < x < 100");

            for (int num= 2; num<= 100; num++)
            {

                prime = True;
                for (int div= 2; div<= Math.Sqrt(num); div++)
                    if(num % div== 0)
                        prime = False;
                if (prime)
                    Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");
            }
        } 
    }
```

The way this works is pretty simple:

It checks if any of the divisors are a factor of the number at hand and if so sets the variable `prime` to false. Otherwise, prime remains true and the number gets printed.

Comment: Hi Monacraft, I have access to answers to this problem already. So thanks for the answers, but I need to know how to think about solving this problem.

Comment: @Code_Steel added explanation, tho its pretty simple

Answer (score -1):

this sounds like an exam question...nevertheless, you should be able to achieve this with the "mod" function.  if "mod" == 0 then prime = false.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the correct code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This program screens all numbers between 1 and 100 for primes and displays the results.");

        for (var numberToPrimeCheck = 2; numberToPrimeCheck <= 100; numberToPrimeCheck++)
        {
            var remainder = 1;
            for (var divisor = 2; divisor <= Math.Sqrt(numberToPrimeCheck); divisor++)
            {
                remainder = numberToPrimeCheck % divisor;
                if (remainder == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (remainder != 0)
                Console.WriteLine(numberToPrimeCheck);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That wont work, it'll print out the numbers each time a number lower then its root is not a factor!